# How to get cell data from flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How can i get cell data from selected row(s) in jquery flexigrid?

I can get column names like this:

```
var abbr = [];
$('.hDiv th', grid).each( function(index){
    abbr[index] = $(this).attr('abbr');
});
```

but how to get data from cells from selected row?

Comment: Solved! :) $('.trSelected td', grid).each(function() {
                alert($(this).text());
        });